# My Android Compound Interest Calculator keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, crash

```
package dum.de.dum;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Bundle;
```

normal imports?

```
public class CalcActivity extends Activity {


    Button finish;
    double total;
    double interest2;
    double time2;
    double base2;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.total);
        finish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View V) {

                EditText base;
                base = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.base);
                String baseValue = base.getText().toString();
                double BaseNum = Double.parseDouble(baseValue);

                EditText interest;
                interest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.interest);
                String interestValue = interest.getText().toString();
                double interestNum = Double.parseDouble(interestValue);

                EditText time;
                time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);
                String timeValue = time.getText().toString();
                double timeNum = Double.parseDouble(timeValue);

                double total = BaseNum * Math.pow(interestNum + 1, timeNum);
```

I've heard that people have had trouble when they parse numbers so I'm not sure if that could be a problem and if it is I have no idea how to fix it

```
        EditText Output;
        Output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total);
        Output.setText("Your total is: " + total);

        };

    });
}
}
```

every time I try to run it in the emulator I immediately get a force close. I'm a new-ish programmer and I don't get any error codes in eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

```
finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.total);
```

The id of your `finish` button isn't `R.id.total` - that's an `EditText` according to this...

```
Output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total);
```

You'll be getting a `ClassCastException` when trying to find the button using that id.

Comment: Wow totally didn't notice that.

Comment: @SmartLemon: It took me a little while before I did. :D

Comment: Since that part of the code was all scrunched up it was sorta harder to notice. D:

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
Output.setText("Your total is: " + total);
```

with:

```
Output.setText("Your total is: " + String.valueOf(total));
```

Comment: What do you mean by both are the same? There is a clear difference in them

Comment: Is it a null exception or what? What does it say in the error? Normally the first few red logs will tell you

Comment: 02-11 06:55:16.852: E/AndroidRuntime(292): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

02-11 06:55:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(292): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dum.de.dum/dum.de.dum.CalcActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText

02-11 06:55:16.862: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)

Comment: @Jake see my answer - I already explained it would be a `ClassCastException`

Comment: @SmartLemon: The first line that you suggest replacing will work fine in the context of concatenating the value of a numeric data type to a String. In this case it will be implicitly converted as part of the concatenation process.

Answer (score 0):

You can see error, by openeing view in eclipse by menu->window->showView->logcat,

As from your description, that application crashes as soon you launch the activity, the problematic area may be:

```
finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.total);
        finish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
```

check once in main.xml button id is given as-> android:id/total

Answer (score 0):

You should also have to show us the Xml layout file because you have first take the finish as a button and then you are assigning the button edit text.
`R.id.total` is button in xml file or a edit text if its is a button have have to use the edittext box id over their in

```
Output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.(edittext button id));
```

then the value will be display on the edit text box.